# Conditional Format Copying in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting, data-validation

I am looking to copy over a conditional format that changes the colour of an array of cells when checking a checkbox.

[image: Conditional Formatting 1]

This works perfectly fine on the first checkbox. However, when I try to replace all the other checkboxes on the spreadsheet with the conditionally formatted cell by dragging down the box, it then messes up all of the formattings. As seen in the picture below.

[image: Conditional Formatting 2]

There has got to be an easier way to do this than to have to create a new rule for every cell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **custom formula: `=COUNTIF($I2, "=TRUE")`**

[image]

Comment: Thank you thats perfect.